# Assiging Plot Range to Variables Works For X but Not Theta

Tags: syntax, core-language, procedural-programming

Observe the following Mathematica code:

```
g1[x_, t_] := Tan[x]*Sin[2 Pi t] + Cot[x]*Cos[2 Pi t];
rs1 := {x, -1.5 \[Pi], 1.5 \[Pi]};
rx1 := {-1.5 \[Pi], 1.5 \[Pi]};
ry1 := rx1;

Animate[Plot[g1[x, t], rs1, PlotRange -> {rx1, ry1}, Axes -> False, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]], {t, 0, 1}, 
 RefreshRate -> 60, AnimationDirection -> Forward, 
 DefaultDuration -> 7]


g3[\[Theta]_, t_] := ArcTan[Sin[2 Pi t + 3 \[Theta]] Sin[3 \[Theta]]];
rs3 := {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]};
rx3 := {-1, 1};
ry3 := rx3;

Animate[PolarPlot[g3[\[Theta], t], rs3, PlotRange -> {rx3, ry3}, 
  Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]], {t, 0, 1}, RefreshRate -> 60, 
 AnimationDirection -> Forward, DefaultDuration -> 7]
```

This is able to successfully plot g1, but it fails to plot g3, stating that "Range specification rs3 is not of the form {x,xmin,xmax}." But I don't understand why it is expecting x when I am using theta. What am I doing wrong? How do I make this work correctly so that it can plot the polar graph g3?

Example screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oluK9.png

Comment: Try `Evaluate@rs3` instead of `rs3`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, thank you, that solved it, but can you explain why it is necessary when using theta but not necessary when using x? To me this just feels arbitrary.

Comment: It's not `theta` vs `x`. It's `PolarPlot` vs. `Plot`.  `Plot` inspects the value of the argument (apparently) if it does not have the right form, which is the case: `rs1` is a symbol, not a list, and therefore `Plot` inspects it.  `PolarPlot` apparently does not and complains instead of inspecting the value of `rs3`.  You might complain to WRI support about the inconsistency. Neither choice is perfect, for technical reasons I don't have time to go into. Probably it was one way, and then they changed `Plot` but not `PolarPlot`. Or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not `θ` vs `x`. It's `PolarPlot` vs. `Plot`. They both have the `HoldAll` attribute.  This is to prevent a value that the variable, either `θ` or `x`, might have outside the plot call from replacing the symbolic variable.  While the plot functions both have the `HoldAll` attribute, they do different things with their arguments.  This is undocumented, and one can only observe their behaviors.  `Plot` inspects the value of the (second) argument (apparently) if the argument does not have the right form, namely, a list: `rs1` as a held argument is a symbol, not a list, and therefore `Plot` inspects it.  It evaluates to a list of the correct form, and `Plot` is happy.  `PolarPlot` apparently does not inspect the symbol `rs3` and complains instead that it is not a list of the correct form. IMO, they should have the same behavior. But they don’t and that’s how it is.

The following fixes the problem if `θ` doesn't have a value:

```
g3[θ_, t_] := 
  ArcTan[Sin[2 Pi t + 3 θ] Sin[3 θ]];
rs3 := {θ, 0, 2 π};
rx3 := {-1, 1};
ry3 := rx3;

Clear[θ];
Animate[PolarPlot[g3[θ, t],
  Evaluate@rs3,
  PlotRange -> {rx3, ry3}, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]], {t, 0, 1}, RefreshRate -> 60, 
 AnimationDirection -> Forward, DefaultDuration -> 7]
```

In both `Plot` and `PolarPlot`, this approach will fail is the variable if `x` or `θ` have a numerical value (respectively).

Here's a quick example how to shoot down the first `Animate`/`Plot` example and make the second `Animate`/`PolarPlot` bullet-proof:

```
x = 10; (* this is the bullet *)
Animate[Plot[g1[x, t], rs1, PlotRange -> {rx1, ry1}, Axes -> False, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]], {t, 0, 1}, 
 RefreshRate -> 60, AnimationDirection -> Forward, 
 DefaultDuration -> 7]

(* $Failed *)
```

This bullet-proofing works on `Plot`, too:

```
θ = 3;  (* the bullet *)
Animate[
 Hold[                 (* READY: the kevlar *)
  g3[θ, t], rs3, PlotRange -> {rx3, ry3}, Axes -> False, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]
  ] /. 
   OwnValues[rs3] /.   (* SET: slip the value under the kevlar *)
   Hold -> PolarPlot,  (* GO! *)
 {t, 0, 1}, RefreshRate -> 60, 
 AnimationDirection -> Forward, DefaultDuration -> 7]
```

This rather roundabout approach doesn't allow `θ` to be evaluated, unlike the `Evaluate@rs3`.